# Find coordinates of point from which two tangents are drawn to a given curve.

Tags: derivatives

[image: Question]

It's a question from the chapter Application of derivatives. All I can understand is that the point will not lie on the curve and the triangle formed will be an equilateral triangle since area for it is maximum for same perimeter.I can't really understand how to proceed after this.

Comment: Did you not try drawing a figure? It becomes self evident that the area will increase as $|h|$ becomes larger and larger

Answer (score 1):

There is no maximum for the area of $PAB$. The lower the point $P\left(\frac{1}{2},h\right)$ is, the larger the area is.

So the answer is d).

Comment: how did you conclude that d would be the right option?

Comment: @MasterMaxx It is none of the other as there is no maximum.